# Scatter plot from data in array

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Hi I would like to graph a very simple scatter plot from vba.
My data are stored in array (result from other calculations).
I do something like that :

```
Option Explicit

Sub graph()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim Fonds As Range, Benchmark As Range
    Dim RdtFonds, RdtBench
    
    Set MyChart = Worksheets("Feuil1").Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlXYScatter).Chart
    
    Set Fonds = Range("B2:B1940")
    Set Benchmark = Range("C2:C1940")
    
    RdtFonds = Rendement(Fonds)
    RdtBench = Rendement(Benchmark)
       
    With MyChart
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Values = Rendement(Fonds)
            .XValues = Rendement(Benchmark)
'            .Trendlines.Add
'            .Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True
'            .Trendlines(1).DisplayRSquared = True
'            .Trendlines(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
'            .Trendlines(1).Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            .MarkerStyle = -4168
            .MarkerSize = 5
        End With
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Fonds vs indice"
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MajorGridlines.Delete
            .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Fonds"
        End With
        With .Axes(xlCategory)
            .MajorGridlines.Delete
            .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Indice"
       End With
    End With
End Sub


Function Rendement(Prix As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, Rdt As Variant
    
    ReDim Rdt(1 To Prix.Rows.Count)
    
    For i = 1 To Prix.Rows.Count
        If i = 1 Then
            Rdt(i) = ""
        Else
            Rdt(i) = Prix(i) / Prix(i - 1) - 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    Rendement = Rdt
End Function
```

but I do not get what I expected. I get:
[image]

It is as if it plots something else. For example when I put my mouse on one point on the graph, I get :
`serie 1 serie "0.04" (1725, 0.002)`
the strange thing is (1725, 0.002) where as I should expect something like :
`serie 1 serie "0.04" "0.002")` I suppose.

Thx for your help

Comment: `Prix(i) / Prix(i - 1)` is being applied to both X and Y values: did you want that?  Might be useful to include a sample screen shot of what your data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

on the left this is what I get and on the right what I expect (I do it from excel). In the middle my data. I know that I apply the same function to the data.

[image]

Comment: I thought that .values and .xvalues were the (x,y) of the point. but not sure. Help